# Can I convert a String variable into a int variable

Tags: java, casting, type-conversion, numberformatexception

Is there a way to get a `Integer` variable from a `String` object, something like:

```
String string = "Render.SCREEN_WIDTH_TILES";
// SCREEN_WIDTH_TILES is a Render Integer value referenced in other class
```

I want the `string` variable to hold the reference to the specified `int`.

What I want from that string value is to "transform it" into a int value,

Is it possible to do this?

**I can't find a way to handle an integer value as a variable in a string.**

Comment: No, you can not evaluate a String like this that's supposed to name another constant.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be misunderstanding how [Integer.parseInt(s)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-) works. The documentation clearly states:

> Parses the string argument ***as a signed decimal integer***. The characters in ***the string must all be decimal digits***, except that the first character may be an ASCII minus sign `-` (`\u002D`) to indicate a negative value or an ASCII plus sign `+` (`\u002B`) to indicate a positive value.

The parameter to `Integer.parseInt(s)` must be a string that contains a number.  Such as:

- `Integer.parseInt("12345")`
- `Integer.parseInt("-45")`

But not:

- `Integer.parseInt("Hello world")`
- `Integer.parseInt("this will not work 4 you")`

And certainly not: `Integer.parseInt("Render.SCREEN_WIDTH_TILES - 1");`

Comment: thank for you answer, any solution to my problem i doubt using parseInt could be the solution, what i need is to convert a string into a int variable is it possible?

Comment: The problem is that it really isn't clear to me what you are trying to do, so I don't see how I can recommend anything useful. All I know for sure is that `Integer.parseInt(s)` is not being used correctly here.

Comment: I update my question hope it's clear now thank you